# how to give the client argument in django management commands?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a function in django management commands that should take a url as an argument

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = u'Enter the url'
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('url',type=str,help=u'Enter the url')

    def handle(self,*args,**kwargs):
        url = kwargs['url']
        main(url)
```

it doesn't matter what the function is, everything in it works when a command is called through the terminal

but I have a question, how can I implement this into the client part? I want the user to enter a url and it is passed to the function.

What are the ways to pass user arguments to django management commands?

Answer (score 0):

the solution turned out to be very simple

you just create a form unrelated to the model, create the fields that you need as an argument in your function, and then pass the data from the form to your command

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddFilmUrl(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            url = form.cleaned_data.get('url')
            management.call_command('parse',url)
    else:
        form = AddFilmUrl()
    return render(request, 'addfilm.html', {'form':form,})
```